# Is it possible : rendering server tags at runtime in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, runtime

Is it possible that I reserve a asp.net code in db and load it at runtime. the asp.net code contains server side tags like `Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'`

Comment: Of course , that's what those tags are for. 
I don't see what are you trying to achieve ?
Eval will evaluate given field from database if your container is DataBound , Bind command will give you two way binding.

Comment: I want reserve this code in db like html code and load it at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to an aspx, plugging in what you want and then build the page using:

```
BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/MyPage.aspx",typeof(Page));
```

You'd need to wrap that when getting your HttpHandler:

```
var p = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/MyPage.aspx",typeof(Page));
HttpContext.Current.Handler =p;
```

(*BuildManager is in* `System.Web.Compilation`)

That's just an idea....but I **wouldn't** do this, as you're going to pay the compilation cost every time (which is really high compared to pretty much any other operation), and you'd need to bump your application files writes before restart (default 15).

Short answer:  **Yes** you can do this, **but I wouldn't**.  There's most likely a much better way to achieve your goal, maybe if you gave a bit more background, we can provide a much better solution.

Comment: I want to give this ability to user that make a returned data form as a grid.

Comment: @masoud ramezani - Does the grid just pull from different columns or, what else changes?

Comment: grid just pull from different columns.

Comment: @masoud ramezani - Something like a GridView with autogenerate columns  (see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) will do this built in, can you describe what behavior different from that you need?

Comment: I want make a report generator for my application and give ability to my end user that generate a form that contains her/his ideals columns.